is front end library Formly future proof?
https://formly.dev/
Im not sure if this is the correct place to start a discussion but here it goes.
Im working on an Angular project which is heavily relying on complex forms and it is expected to be live for the next 10+ years. We need to rewrite the current forms and are considering if we should use front end library Formly as it is very powerful and will cover a lot of the business cases and requirements.
Question is: is Formly future proof? I think only one person is maintaining this library which is a big concern, what happens if he doesnt want to maintain it anymore? I cant understand if this library has been accepted by the community but i dont see any valid alternative as well?
Any feedback of anyone who has used the library would be appreciated.

nothing is future proof, but you can just build your application through reactive forms, angular supports it and has a rich ecosystem to support it. Else trust the formly ecosystem, but going plain angular is the safest course!

Using formly on my project, and tbh I can't recommand it, unless you are only using basic forms. As soon as you start to need more complex custom forms (validation, UI...), formly start to become a nightmare. Hard to find resources, documentation is poor, adding unecessary complexity for features that should be straigh forward. Ofc this is a personal opinion and formly can have some uses, but we are condidering getting rid of it to be back on good old reactive forms.
